# Set link height to 100% of it's parent

Tags: css, height

If I have division with `height: 100px;` and it contains a link inside - can I make link fill the height of the division without hard-coding the value?

`<div><a href="#">hello</a></div>`

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: red;
}

a {
    background: green;
    height: 100%; /* This does not work. Is it possible to set this height to 100% of container? */
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPL65/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add:

```
display: block;
height: 100%;
```

Though I don't know if you mind the link spanning the width of the `<div>`

If you do just set the `<a>` to `display: inline-block;`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nPL65/2/)

Comment: If you want it to fill the whole div, change it to `min-height:100%`

Answer (score 3):

Yes.. it is possible, only when you set its  display to block

```
div {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
}

a{
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    background: green;
}
```

As you can see, the background fills with green instead red.. it proves the height is setting actually

Answer (score 2):

Block elements will expand to fill their container, specifying height as 100% will cause it to increase to the height of its parent.

```
a {
    background: green;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/h42bD/